# How to generate a Report with a SubReport that has more than one page using FastReport and Delphi 7

Tags: delphi, printing, delphi-7, reportbuilder

I have a Report and in my Detail i put a SubReport with the following properties:

[image: Properties]

When the SubReport has more than one page, the next page gets blank, like in the images following:

[image: SubReport]

[image: Blank Page]

It looks like, this next blank page, is related to the SubReport data, but it doesn't show anything, and after this blank space, the report keep normaly showing the rest of the data.

Anyone knows what can i do to show the data of the subReport when he generates more tha one page?

Answer (score 0):

Try to set TfrxSubreport.PrintOnParent to True
You don't use Fast Report's TfrxSubreport on the Properties screenshot. TppSubReport is not FR's class

Comment: i'm not using TfrxSubreport, i'm using ppSubReport, that don't have the propertie PrintOnParent

Comment: So, you use another report generator. Not Fast Report

Comment: I can't change the report generator every time i have a problem. Even because my company uses this component.

Comment: But you can edit this topic (type Report Builder instead of Fast Report ). May be Report Builder users can help you